# When Logging In: Admin is loading Extremely long

Tags: ee2, admin, slow

I have an old EE site that I haven't logged into for a year. Now I'm trying to login to it, but it's taking over 1 minute just to log in...

After I'm finally logged in every consequent page load in the admin also takes over a minute to load.

The thing is: I changed Nothing. All I did was not login for a year and now when I try to login it just loads for ages.

Before I thought it might be the 3000 pending comments that are causing this, so I deleted them in the database to see, but it didn't improve one bit. It's still crazy slow.

My EE version is 2.0

Please suggest how to fix this, I have no idea where to start and I can't work on the admin to try things because it's too slow.

P.S. the font end still loads fine and speedy.

Comment: Turn on debugging, amigo, and analyze what's taking so long: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html

Comment: I can't even get to that anymore now. Now when I try to login I get this:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 2006

MySQL server has gone away

SELECT LOWER(module_name) AS name FROM (`cms_modules`) ORDER BY `module_name`

Filename: libraries/Cp.php

Line Number: 904

Comment: I optmized the database tables also but that didn't help

Comment: I was just able to get to the debugging settings, but the output of the debug does not show me anything that rings a bell with me (only that loading took 127 seconds and memory usage was 17,000,000 bytes). Database output and excecution time seems normal to me. Please have a look at the debug output in this screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/05b56mcm57
Do you see anything that rings a bell there?

Answer (score 0):

Hrmmm.. a site I have that that has all of the major addons, and has had 25 thousand unique visitors in the last 24 hours, only hits 12mb of memory usage... but...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

You connection to the MySQL sever has gone wonky!

Your connection between your application server and your database server is suffering hard. This could be a host issue, or it could be a configuration issue. Check with your host to see if they've upgraded any infrastructure, or any software (MySQL, etc...) recently. Also, SSH into your application server, and ping your database server. What do you see?

Also, if they are the same server, run this command in a bash shell:

```
top
```

What are we seeing? You may also need to run a repair on your database, or better yet, restart your MySQL server agent.

Take all of this with a grain of salt; something is wrong, and you should **definitely** back up your entire database and, just for poops and giggles, your web root as well.

Comment: i just opened a ticket at hostgator, my old shared hosting account where this website still resides on. I pointed them to this thread also. SSH isn't possible with shared right? I tried a repair on the database as well but that didn't help. I did do a backup.

Comment: SSH is possible on shared hosting, but it really depends on your host and your plan. Poke around in your cPanel/whatever and see if you can enable it.

Comment: I looked around but couldn't find anything about SSH. Waiting for hostgator to reply still... Been 24 hours+, no reply. Typical HostGator service nowadays. since EIG took over the company.